# How to transform constant value to Query/Rep for unionAll

Tags: scala, slick

There is a some table `Users` with fields `id`, `name`, etc

I need to select some ids from `Users` and concatenate with some constant value `A`. For example, I want to get the following result:

```
                  id                  
--------------------------------------
 someId-1
 someId-2
 someId-3
 A
```

I can do it with plain sql in the following way:

```
SELECT id FROM users UNION ALL SELECT 'A';
```

How can I do it with slick?
For example:

```
val q: Query[UsersTable, Users, Seq] = ...
q.map(_.id).unionAll( "A" ) //TODO how to transform "A" to query or Rep
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the answer how to create a Slick `Query` from a constant into is rather trivial: just use [`slick.lifted.Query.apply`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/api/index.html#slick.lifted.Query$) from companion object such as

```
q.map(_.id).unionAll( Query("A") )
```